# What does the word "pararail" mean?

Tags: terminology

What does the word "pararail" mean? I would like to know the meaning. Search over web does not help much.

Comment: Context may be important. Do you have a link or a quote?

Comment: Asking for the definition of a word is off-topic on this site unless the word is related to engineering.  Please give your question some context.  What field does this term arise in?  Where did you run into it?

Comment: I am sorry that your question has been closed. I googled for the word and didn't find any meaning. It seems to be some like a company name. Your question was closed probably because nobody understood the word here. Please don't take it seriously - I suggest to investigate a little bit after this, and then edit your partial info in your question. I voted to reopen your question but it will have probably more chance if you would extend it somehow.

Comment: The question has a good-looking answer, maybe it deserves a reopen.

Comment: @peterh  Reopening would allow *more* answers; what's the point? The upvoted answer will keep the question from being automatically deleted and additional answers would not make the question any more clear, less broad or more on-topic.

Comment: @Air As the upvoted answer shows, the question was not unclear. Thus its close as an unclear question is not reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

If this was a quiz show and you had one guess, the safest offering may be 'The suspension system in a vintage Scorpion snowmobile", **BUT**

"Para rail" and "pararail" are 'made up' words usually used as product names and/or trademarks for a range of things by a range of manufacturers over a range of years.

Google's ngram viewer swears it does not know the word - usually a goodish sign that a term is a specialist one.

---

**Here are some of the available "pararails":**

[Steyr AUG Rifle foward grip slide **pararail**](http://www.tactical-life.com/gear/suarez-international-advanced-aug-forward-para-rail-one-source-tactical-new-product/#suarez-international-advanced-aug-forward-para-rail-_-new-product-1) - the slide rail mid picture.
Guess: Paratroop rail

[image]

[**Pararail** suspension on a vintage scorpion snowmobile](http://www.vintagesnowmobile.com/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1210039557)
Guess: Wazzat?

Also [here](http://www.vintagesledders.com/forums/index.php?topic=966.20)
and [here](http://classicsnowmobiles.blogspot.co.nz/2015_02_01_archive.html)

[image]

[Same name](http://wssafety.com/products/rooftop-guardrails-safety-rail-2000/architectural-series/) same type of product different company.

[Pararail rooftop fall protection system](http://www.all-liftsystems.com/products/safetyfall-protectionguardrail-systemsmodular-railing-systems/railing-kits/pararail-1)
Guess: Parapet rail

[image]

[Many maybes](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=pararail&biw=1776&bih=1063&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=U0NgVYj9L4v48QWc8ICgBQ&ved=0CC4QsAQ)